# 2k factorial effect interpretation

Tags: interpretation, experiment-design, nonparametric

Say if I run a 2k factorial experiment with 3 variables: A, B, & C.  For variable A it is varied parametrically, e.g. "-" = old parts, "+" = new parts.  If my main effect of A is negligible and the interactions containing A are negligible is it reasonable to assume that there is either negligible difference in A- and A+ or that the differences in A have little effect on the response variable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by saying that A is varied parametrically. Do you mean that A has only 2 levels? Anyway, it seems to make no difference whether you use old parts or new parts. That's the interpretation. If "old parts" is the baseline, then the effect of "A" is the difference between new parts and old parts. The hypothesis test is that this difference is 0.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.  I was trying to say that it's not continuous.